# gae:run has no errors but accessing the app or admin console ends up in 404 not found

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, maven-gae-plugin

I'm trying to run a jsf project on the app engine development server.

I'm using Eclipse Juno, maven-gae-plugin 0.9.5, jsf 2.1 and gae-jdk 1.7.3 on Windows 7 with jdk 1.6.32.

What I did so far (amongst others, but this try was the most successful, hopefully):

- Created a maven project using the gae-jsf archetype in eclipse
- Checked versions in pom
- Override the WebConfiguration.java
- Set log-level to FINE
- ...

FInally, it seems to work, if I run mvn gae:run, the whole process runs straight forward with no exceptions. It ends uf with

```
FINE: File added: C:\ws_eclipse\myapp\target\myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
Nov 10, 2012 4:05:34 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractBackendServers startupAll
FINE: Got null backendsXml config.
Nov 10, 2012 5:05:34 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8080/
Nov 10, 2012 5:05:34 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

If I then try to access either my application or the adminconsole via the browser, I always get a 404 Not Found".

Has anybody a hint?

Comment: Using gae-maven-plugin 0.9.2, this works. I can access the admin console, but have a stackoverflow in my app. Think, this has nothing to do with maven.